# Ins-completion C-X C-F and the path variable

Tags: insert-mode, path, ins-completion

Can the insert-completion of file names <kbd>CTRL+X</kbd><kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> can be used to complete filenames that are not in the current working directory ? But rather in any in the `path` variable ?

Can we, for example, override (with pain I guess) the <kbd>CTRL+X</kbd><kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> mapping to take `path` (or only the path of the current buffer) into account ?

Also, `:h compl-filename` says

> Note: the 'path' option is not used here (yet).

Are there any effort in making the "(yet)" part obsolete ? How hard would it be to implement it ?

Comment: Replace `getcompletion()` with `globpath()` in the answer to get the desired functionality.